# mathtools vs amsmath

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, mathtools

I read on http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics:

> The `mathtools` package fixes some `amsmath` quirks and adds some useful
>   settings, symbols, and environments to `amsmath`.

It sounds like "`mathtools` has everything that `amsmath` has and more", isn't it?

Are there cases when it is justified to use `amsmath` instead of `mathtools`?

In other words: Is `mathtools` "always" better?

Comment: `mathtools` is an add on to `amsmath`

Comment: See https://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/msg/2cddb7e230d50439

Comment: If it was not clear from @MarcoDaniel's comment, the `mathtools` package includes the `amsmath` package.

Comment: @Peter `load` might be a better word, `mathtools` does not come with its own version of `amsmath`;-)

Comment: So, maybe someone more competent would like to fix this page of LaTeX Wikibook ? :)

Comment: @daleif: One of the lines of code in `mathtools` is `\RequirePackage{amsmath}`, so that contents of `amsmath` are included/loaded/imported by `mathtools`. Since I do not know of `load` as being part of the LaTeX syntax, I think include would be a better choice (but did not use syntax highlighting as in `include` to indicate that it was a keyword). English not be my bestest :-) so leave it up to others to select the correct word.

Comment: Grzegorz: go right ahead. :) But based on the discussion I think the existing text is pretty accurate.

Comment: Why do you say ¨Certainly mathtools is not a replacement package for amsmath. This is clear from the package author's comments in the abstract and the introduction¨ if mathtools has amsmath inside then mathtools is a replacement... cause mathtools=amsmath+other stuffs

Comment: Is there any alternative to the mathtool package?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I believe that the answer has been provided, mostly in the comments but here is a short summary:

The `mathtools` package loads the `amsmath` package, if it has not already been loaded. This is common in many packages that need to ensure that dependencies are loaded. If you have a look in `mathtools.sty` line 60, you will see:

```
  \RequirePackage{amsmath}[2000/07/18]
```

As such if you only load `mathtools`, you will have both packages loaded and you do not need to `\usepackage{amsmath}` in your preamble. To see this you can run the following minimal:

```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{mathtools}
  \makeatletter
   \@ifpackageloaded{amsmath}{
     \AtBeginDocument{True amsmath is loaded\par}}{}
   \makeatother
  \begin{document}
  \end{document}
```

Certainly `mathtools` is not a replacement package for `amsmath`. This is clear from the package author's comments in the abstract and the introduction:

> The mathtools package is an extension package to amsmath

Hope the above will help you a bit more as to how to find your way around LaTeX and the many packages that are available.