# Align text to left, equation in center

Tags: align

I want to write down some equations, with some commentary between the equations. However, the equations need to be aligned and I want the commentary to be aligned to the left. My code is:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
a+c&= b +d\\
a&= b+ d-c\\
\mbox{text at the left}\\
0&=b+d - a-c    
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Is this possible within the `align` environment?

Comment: `\intertext{}` is the command you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{align} 
a+c&= b +d\\
a&= b+ d-c\\ 
\shortintertext{text at the left} 
0&=b+d - a-c    
\end{align}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the text is longer than in your example, you should use `\intertext` instead. The latter is included in `amsmath` as well.

Comment: It might be helpful to note that the `\shortintertext{}` macro here requires the [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package, whereas `\intertext{}` requires only the [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package.

Comment: @darthbith Thanks. I had no idea. Thought both is from `mathtools`.

Comment: Nonetheless, I usually load `mathtools` since I have no legacy documents that might be changed by the changes in `mathtools` as compared to `amsmath`. Actually, `mathtools` provides some fixes to `intertext` and `shortintertext` (See page 23 of the [`mathtools` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools/mathtools.pdf)), so it is probably better to load `mathtools`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43860/32374 .