# Placing labels equidistant from a line segment

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a display of similar triangles - one inscribed in another.  2.5mm below one line segment, the labels C and C_1 are positioned.  Actually, 2.5mm below the line segment, the centers of the nodes for C and C_1 are positioned.  The subscript on C_1 is preventing them from being equidistant from the line segment.  How do I make them equidistant?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}


\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}




\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B') at (50:7.5);
\path[name path=ray_k] (A) -- (B');
\coordinate (C') at (15:7.5);
\path[name path=ray_ell] (A) -- (C');


%This command labels a point "B" 3.75cm from A on ray $k$.
\coordinate (B) at (50:{15/4});
\draw (A) -- (B);

%These commands label the projection of AB onto \ell "C."  A line segment is drawn between
%B and C, and a right-angle mark is placed at C.
\coordinate (C) at ($(A)!(B)!(C')$);

\draw (B) -- (C);

%These commands draw a right-angle mark at C.
\coordinate (U) at ($(C)!3mm!-45:(A)$);
\draw (U) -- ($(C)!(U)!(A)$);
\draw (U) -- ($(C)!(U)!(B)$);


%These commands draw an invisible line segment perpendicular to ray k from B to
%ray $\ell$. The intersection is labeled C_1.
\path[name path=perpendicular_line_segment_from_B] (B) -- ($(B)!3.5cm!90:(A)$);
\coordinate[name intersections={of=perpendicular_line_segment_from_B and ray_ell, by={C_1}}];


%The following commands define B_1 as the intersection of k and a line segment
%perpendicular to $\ell$ through C_1. A line segment is drawn between
%B_1 and C_1, and a right-angle mark is placed at C_1.
\path[name path=perpendicular_line_segment_from_C_1] (C_1) -- ($(C_1)!4cm!90:(C')$);
\coordinate[name intersections={of=perpendicular_line_segment_from_C_1 and ray_k, by={B_1}}];
\draw (C_1) -- (B_1);

%These commands draw a right-angle mark at C_1.
\coordinate (U_1) at ($(C_1)!3mm!-45:(A)$);
\draw (U_1) -- ($(C_1)!(U_1)!(A)$);
\draw (U_1) -- ($(C_1)!(U_1)!(B_1)$);


%This command draws the two sides of the triangle with a common vertex A.
\draw (A) -- (B_1);
\draw (A) -- (C_1);



%These commands draw an invisible line segment 2.5mm below AD for labels C and C_1.
\coordinate (A_shift_for_labels) at ($(A)!2.5mm!-90:(C_1)$);
\coordinate (C_1_shift_for_labels) at ($(C_1)!2.5mm!90:(A)$);
\path[name path=path_for_labels_C_and_C_1] (A_shift_for_labels) -- (C_1_shift_for_labels);
\coordinate (C_below) at ($(C)!-0.75cm!(B)$);
\path[name path=path_from_B_to_C_below] (B) -- (C_below);
\coordinate (C_1_below) at ($(C_1)!-0.75cm!(B_1)$);
\path[name path=path_from_B_1_to_C_1_below] (B_1) -- (C_1_below);
\coordinate[name intersections={of=path_for_labels_C_and_C_1 and path_from_B_to_C_below, by={C_label}}];
\coordinate[name intersections={of=path_for_labels_C_and_C_1 and path_from_B_1_to_C_1_below, by={C_1_label}}];
\node[green] at (C_label){$C$};
\node[green] at (C_1_label){$C_{1}$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `$\strut C$`

Comment: or `\node[green] at (C_label){$C_{\phantom{1}}$};`

Comment: or `[anchor=base]` or `[anchor=mid]` or `[anchor=north]` or whichever you prefer...

Comment: @Ignasi  I like the spacing of "C" in this case.  Can I get the space occupied by the subscript "1" to be ignored?

Comment: @percusse I would like the "$C_{1}$" moved.  How do I use `$\strut C$`?

Comment: @user74973 to ignore only the vertical space `$C\smash{_{1}}$` can be used.

Comment: @Kpym   The `\smash` command does ignore the vertical space, and both `C` and `C_1` are typeset equidistant from the ray.  It does not ignore the horizontal space, and the "C" in `C_1` is displaced leftward.  How do I get `TikZ` to ignore the area the subscript occupies when positioning `C_1`?

Comment: @user74973 if you want to ignore both (width and height) you can use `$C\mathrlap{\smash{_{1}}}$`. To be able to use `\mathrlap` you have to replace `amsmath` with `mathtools`. Probably this is not the best way to do it, but it works for me.

Comment: @Kpym  Yeah, I don't want to get away from `amsmath`.   I tried using an `mbox[0pt]` to get `TikZ` to ignore the subscript in the following command:  `\node[green] at (C_1_label){$C\smash{\makebox[0pt]{${}_{1}$}}$};`.  The subscript is typeset flush against the `C`, though.

Comment: @user74973 You don't go away from `amsmath` by replacing it with `mathtools`, who is an extension of `amsmath` AND loads it. You can ckeck [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43860/9335).

Comment: @Kpym  Another member, cfr, suggested the following edits to my code. He put `\newlength\myshift` and `\settowidth{\myshift}{$_1$}` before the `tikzpicture` environment, and he put `\node[blue, xshift=.5\myshift] at (B_1_label){$B_{1}$};` and `\node[blue, xshift=.5\myshift] at (C_1_label){$C\smash{_{1}}$};` in the code. I like what he did.   The code does typeset, for example, the `C` in `C_1` at the position called `C_1_label` just as it would typeset `C` at `C_1_label`.

Comment: @Kpym  I understand that `\myshift` occupies the same width as the subscript `1`. How does `xshift=.5\myshift` "cancel" the width occupied by `1`?