# How can I deactivate hyperref but keep the bookmarks bar?

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks

I don't want the readers jumping on text by mistakenly clicking on author names or figure/table numbers. So I want to disable hyperref but still keep the bookmark sidebar in the pdf file. Bookmarks are kind of like toc and help the reader jump on references or appendices whenever they want.

So I want a combination of "nohyperref" and "bookmarks=true", but i don't know how to get it done.

Thanks.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.8}
\usepackage{soul} 
\sethlcolor{light-gray}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,shadings,shapes,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{times}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage[nokeyprefix]{refstyle}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{References.bib}
@article{cite1,
title={Nothing special},
author={Nobody, Noboditch},
year={1988}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}


\section{Introduction}
 \onehalfspacing
 \citep[see, e.g.,][]{cite1}


\section*{}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}

\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{References}

\end{document}
```

So I want the links to citations be disabled but "introduction" and "References" to appear in bookmarks.

Comment: @Sebastiano there is a `bookmark` package... You already have +1 from me... but with this package I think your answer will fit his expectations

Comment: @D_B Into your code you have `\usepackage{amsmath}` and `\usepackage{mathtools}`. The last package is strong and contains  `\usepackage{amsmath}`. See this link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43860/mathtools-vs-amsmath

Comment: Your long list of packages seems quite likely copied from some friend's template; don't do like this, use only the packages you really need. For instance, it's very dubious to load both `mathpazo` (for Palatino in text and math) and `times` (for Times New Roman in text): you end up with Times for text and Palatino for math, a very awkward combination.

Comment: You might use the `hidelinks` option.

Comment: hidelinks hides only the blue borders but doesn't disable the links.

Comment: @Sebastiano... A downvote to an answer of an unclear question is something we have to avoid... Thus my upvote was to show this fact and to wait from you to edit after the MWE.

Comment: @koleygr You're right. Never I have thought for the points in this community. And believe me with all my heart, I don't want to fight with anyone. As soon as I write something that someone doesn't like slightly, after a few minutes the downvote arrives. I don't care about anything, but I had nothing in my hands.

Comment: @D_B What's the reason for disabling the links? I mean, you want the bookmarks which *are* links.

Comment: Bookmarks are showed on the sidebar. Links are within the text. I don't ant the latter. @egreg

Comment: @D_B my code in the deleted answer had sidebar (click-able that was going to the section) but not clickable in-text references (i tested on linux). But if draft removed figures then it was not ok for you and deleted

Comment: @koleygr bookmarks sidebar doesn't show up in the pdf!

Comment: Please download the pdf from here and check it: https://v2.overleaf.com/read/nzrmtkzxtbkf. If you have problem with sidebar ("outline" in evince viewer for me) is probably your viewer problem. You have to turn on the option or something. Check other documents too

Comment: @koleygr I downloaded your version and tried both adobe reader and professional. It doesn't show side bar in my pc.

Comment: @D_B, did you tried with other document that you know it shows sidebar? May be sidebar is not the same that I mean. I mean a bar (for me in the left) that shows the sections and you can navigate inside them by clicking on the names of the sections

Comment: Yes, I meant the same sidebar. This is strange!

Comment: @D_B I am deleting my answer since you are rigth. The bookmarks shows on my viewer but aren't clickable and thus your clever viewer is hiding tthem. I think we have to delete some comments here to let people help you easier without seeing all these comments. When agree just comment here.

Comment: Please check last edit and tell me to delete some unuseful comments from here.

Answer (score 4):

There is no in-built option to disable the links apart from the `draft` option. But these also disables the anchors and so bookmarks no longer have a target.

You could try to execute only a part of the commands used by the `draft` option. Be aware that while it works in the minimal example it could be that in larger documents you get errors because of some side-effect - hyperref is a rather complicated beast.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bookmark}%loads hyperref
\makeatletter
\gdef\hyper@link#1#2#3{#3\Hy@xspace@end}
\gdef\hyper@link#1#2#3{#3\Hy@xspace@end}%
\let\hyper@linkstart\@gobbletwo
\def\hyper@linkend{\Hy@xspace@end}%
%\def\hyper@linkurl#1#2{#1\Hy@xspace@end}   % url optional
%\def\hyper@linkfile#1#2#3{#1\Hy@xspace@end}%files optional
\def\hyper@link@[#1]#2#3#4{#4\Hy@xspace@end}%
\let\@fifthoffive\@secondoftwo  %unclear if needed
\let\@secondoffive\@secondoftwo %unclear if needed
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First section}
\ref{test} is on page \pageref{test}

\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}
\newpage
\section{Second section}\label{test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For some reason `\let\@secondoffive\@secondoftwo` messed up my page number. Without it worked nicely.

Answer (score 2):

**Last Edit:** We create  bookmarks manually and using the previous methods. On my linux (okular and evince) bookmarks are in the sidebar and active, and all links in the document are inactive.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.8}
\usepackage{soul} 
\sethlcolor{light-gray}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,shadings,shapes,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{times}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage[nokeyprefix]{refstyle}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{xr}

\usepackage[depth=-1]{bookmark}

\hypersetup{draft}
\PassOptionsToPackage{draft}{bookmark}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{References.bib}
@article{cite1,
title={Nothing special},
author={Nobody, Noboditch},
year={1988}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}\bookmark[page=\thepage,level=0]{Introduction}

 \onehalfspacing
 \citep[see, e.g.,][]{cite1}
 This is a reference \ref{sec:test}
\lipsum[1-5]

\section{Test}\label{sec:test}\bookmark[page=\thepage,level=0]{Test}
\lipsum[1-5]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\subsection{Test subsection}\bookmark[page=\thepage,level=1]{Test subsection}
\lipsum[1-3]
\section*{}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}

\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{References}\bookmark[page=\thepage,level=0]{References}

\end{document}
```

**First answer**

Here is a solution with `bookmark` package. I removed hyperref as you don't really need it:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt,draft]{article}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.8}
\usepackage{soul} 
\sethlcolor{light-gray}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,shadings,shapes,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{times}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage[nokeyprefix]{refstyle}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{xr}
%\usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{References.bib}
@article{cite1,
title={Nothing special},
author={Nobody, Noboditch},
year={1988}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\setlength\overfullrule{0pt}

\begin{document}


\section{Introduction}
 \onehalfspacing
 \citep[see, e.g.,][]{cite1}
 This is a reference \ref{sec:test}
\lipsum[1-5]

\section{Test}\label{sec:test}
\lipsum[1-3]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,draft=false]{example-image-a}
\section*{}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}

\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{References}

\end{document}
```

Edit: added draft option in document class and checked... Also, I had to add `[draft=false]` option for the pictures and everything is fine. Test it.

**Edit:** Added \setlength\overfullrule{0pt} and changed `\usepackage{hypre-xr}` to `\usepackage{xr}` thanks to @blub.

Also from his comment, a better alternative (to avoid writing `draft=false` in every image) is to add the code:

```
 \makeatletter \lowercase{\Gin@boolkey{false}}{draft} \makeatother
```

in our preamble

Comment: The code gives some error that haven't figured out yet about a label or something... In your full example may be it is ok... But as MWE it has some problem even if compiles

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry for my messy code.
But the citation is still linked to the references section.

Comment: Only \usepackage{nohyperref} breaks the link, but also bookmarks.

Comment: @koleygr even in your code the citation is linked to the references.

Comment: @D_B.. I edited and aded Draft and seems to work. But you have to check it in your real document because possibly will give other problems

Comment: @koleygr "draft" removed bookmarks as well. Plus figures don't show.

Comment: To remove the black lines caused by the `draft` option, add `\setlength\overfullrule{0pt}`

Comment: @blub... Thanks, solves the problem but adds an error

Comment: @koleygr Strange, I don't get an error. I'll test again. Meanwhile to show images despite draft mode: `\makeatletter
\lowercase{\Gin@boolkey{false}}{draft}
\makeatother`

Comment: @koleygr Checked again and `\setlength\overfullrule{0pt}` works. Where did you place it? Without hyperref better change `\usepackage{xr-hyper}` to `\usepackage{xr}`

Comment: @blub, I forgot the \setlength and the error was wired to make me find the problem ("A number should have been here...")... Thank you.. Fixed. Do you have a sidebar with the chapters in your viewer?

Comment: @koleygr Did you try the `\Gin@boolkey`?

Comment: @blub... Yes... It works. (Had lost that comment)... If you make it an answer I will upvote (the half of mine is already yours).

Comment: @koleygr You had the good idea that solves the problem, my comments are just minor.

Comment: @blub... Please confirm that there is a sidebar in your pdf viewer and tell us witch viewer is it. OP cant see a sidebar. Thanks for everything... I will add the alternative (`\Gin@boolkey`) too

Comment: @koleygr Was AFK, sorry. Both the texstudio viewer and adobe reader show the bookmarks in the sidebar.

Comment: @blub the bookmarks was shown there but was inactive... They all linked to page 1 at the time I gave the edited answer. My last edit is ok with everything (now) I think. Works fine. Even if doesn't use your code I am thankfull that learned from you. (Upvoted other answers of you)