# From lmodern to newtx (with amsmath and other AMS packages)

Tags: fonts, amsmath, newtxmath, newtx

I need to change the font from `lmodern` to Times belonging to `newtx` package.

Started with this MWE

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\input{glyphtounicode}
\pdfgentounicode=1

\usepackage[centertags,intlimits,namelimits,sumlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}


\begin{document}

\(f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}\) such that
\begin{align*}
  f(25) &= f(5^2) \\
  &= f(3^2 + 4^2) \\
  &= f(3) + f(4)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

...and got to this MWE

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\input{glyphtounicode}
\pdfgentounicode=1

\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[centertags,intlimits,namelimits,sumlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}


\begin{document}

\(f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}\) such that
\begin{align*}
  f(25) &= f(5^2) \\
  &= f(3^2 + 4^2) \\
  &= f(3) + f(4)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

The latter does not compile successfully (but it did last year on March 18, with the following versions: `newtxtext 2018/03/27 v1.531`, `newtxmath 2018/05/15 v1.553`, `amsmath 2018/12/01 v2.17b AMS math features`, `amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support`, `amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols`):

```
amssymb.sty:261: LaTeX Error: Command `\Bbbk' already defined.
```

Putting a comment on `\usepackage{amssymb}` resolves the issue, but there are few remarks on using `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` along with AMS stuff in `newtx` manual which I probably misinterpret.

1. In general, how can I shift to `newtx` still using features that I used to have with `lmodern`?
2. Is there a better way of setting `amsmath` options? Note the somewhat weird order of `newtxtext`, `amsmath` and `newtxmath`.

Regards

Comment: Never use `minimal` for tests, unless you're testing package loading options. Not for documents to be typeset.

Comment: OK, thank you for the advice. It did not work for `Book` as well.

Comment: Things compile fine if you load `newtxmath` after rather than before `amssymb`. But then, as @egreg has pointed out in his answer, you needn't load `amssymb` to begin with, since all the symbols defined by `amssymb` are also defined by `newtxmath`.

Comment: You can also remove `lmodern` if loading `newtxtext` (as the answers do).

Comment: If you can use a modern TeX engine, you could also load `unicode-math` and set the math font to `TeX Gyre Termes Math`, a clone of `newtx`.

Comment: "You can also remove lmodern if loading newtxtext (as the answers do)." It is not that I can, I must not use it, and that is the first thing I did, check my second MWE ;).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need neither `amsfonts` nor `amssymb` when you load `newtxmath`, that covers everything the two packages do.

Since `newtxmath` loads `amsmath`; if you want to pass options to `amsmath`, load it earlier.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % unnecessary for releases 2018 and later of LaTeX 

\input{glyphtounicode}
\pdfgentounicode=1

\usepackage[centertags,intlimits,namelimits,sumlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}


\begin{document}

\(\lessapprox\)

\(f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}\) such that
\begin{align*}
  f(25) &= f(5^2) \\
  &= f(3^2 + 4^2) \\
  &= f(3) + f(4)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Any special reason behind putting `\lessapprox` in the example?

Comment: @ivankokan I chose a lesser used symbol of `amssymb` at random.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\input{glyphtounicode}
\pdfgentounicode=1

\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[centertags,intlimits,namelimits,sumlimits]{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\begin{document}

\(f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}\) such that
\begin{align*}
  f(25) &= f(5^2) \\
  &= f(3^2 + 4^2) \\
  &= f(3) + f(4)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Compiles fine for me.

Note that `amsfonts` is already included in `amssymb` (so you don't need to load it twice). And using `mathtools` instead of `amsmath` is not mandatory, but [it improves](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43860/172164) some aspects of `amsmath`. And except if you're using an older version of LaTeX or your file isn't UTF-8 encoded, `[utf8]{inputenc}` can be omitted as it has become standard in 2018 .

Comment: I am aware of `utf8` being the default, it is still there for other not-so-Unicode-friendly co-editors. :) I have up-to-date MiKTeX installed, let me check versions later when I get home. Do you have the latest? (My second MWE used to work last year but now it does not.)

Comment: Ah ok, just checking! `:)` I ran it on pdfTeX: Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20, MiKTeX: 2.9.7250 64-bit.

Comment: I am also aware of `mathtools`. Here I prepared MWEs, in full setup I load that later in the preamble.