# Conflict of mathtools and amsmath?

Tags: mathtools

I was using this template: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/university-of-michigan-dissertation-template-unofficial/tpnjzndnrzmf

As long as I add `\usepackage{mathtools}` in package.tex, there is a "!" after Appendices.

[image]

I suspect this is because of the conflict between mathtools and amsmath after reading this:
[mathtools vs amsmath](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43860/mathtools-vs-amsmath)

But even if I comment out `\RequirePackage{amsmath}` in thesis-umich.cls, the problem is still present. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal example showing this? I could not reproduce

Comment: And exactly how does that page say there is a conflict between amsmath and mathtools?

Comment: Here's a test, does that ! Appear if you load calc or graphicx instead of mathtools (it loads those two)

Comment: As expected this is nt caused by `mathtools` it self, but by `calc`. One can cut the error down to `\documentclass{thesis-umich}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}
test

\appendix

test
\end{document}` and btw this generates an error. Don't ignore errors just because it produces a PDF, the PDF may contain the wrong output.

Answer (score 9):

The problem has nothing to do with `mathtools` it self, but rather to it loading the `calc` package`. So we can reduce the problem to

```
\documentclass{thesis-umich} 
\usepackage{calc} 
\begin{document} 
test  
\appendix  
test 
\end{document}
```

which produces the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@calc@post@scan ...st@scan \else \def \calc@next 
                                                  {\calc@error #1}\fi \fi \f...
l.11 \appendix
```

When using Overleaf, please never ever ignore compilation errors. Overleaf, like many LaTeX editors run in a mode that tries to complete the compilation even if there are errors. This may cause issues in the PDF with things not being typeset correctly. Often a single error causes many others ...

The problem her is this definition in `thesis-umich.cls`

```
\renewcommand{\appendix}{ %
 % Move to new page.
 \clearpage %
 % Renew the counters.
 \renewcommand*{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}} %
 % Start over the chapter counter.
 \setcounter{chapter}{0} %
 % Add a pdf anchor.
 \phantomsection %
 % Add blank space to table of contents
 \addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{3.9ex}}
 % Add the page to the table of contents.
 \addcontentsline{toc}{backchapter}{Appendices}
 % Stop adding sections to the table of contents.
 \addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}} %
 % Header for appendices.
 \renewcommand{\@chapapp}{APPENDIX} %
 % Renew the chapter and section labels.
 \let\@chapter\@chapter@appendix %
}
```

especially the line

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}} %
```

whenever `calc` is loaded, `\setcounter` becomes a fragile command, and this it needs protection (from premature expansion) when being written to a file.

So here the fix is to add this to your preamble (don't change the cls file, rather send those maintaining it a message and ask them to fix it).

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\appendix}{ %
 % Move to new page.
 \clearpage %
 % Renew the counters.
 \renewcommand*{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}} %
 % Start over the chapter counter.
 \setcounter{chapter}{0} %
 % Add a pdf anchor.
 \phantomsection %
 % Add blank space to table of contents
 \addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{3.9ex}}
 % Add the page to the table of contents.
 \addcontentsline{toc}{backchapter}{Appendices}
 % Stop adding sections to the table of contents.
 \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}} % <-----
 % Header for appendices.
 \renewcommand{\@chapapp}{APPENDIX} %
 % Renew the chapter and section labels.
 \let\@chapter\@chapter@appendix %
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: we should fix mathtools not to make setcounter fragile

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it's not `mathtools` that does that its `calc`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you should probably fix `mathtools` so it does not use `calc`, but that does not make the `calc` problems go away.

Comment: yes not using calc would be good here. But as you say we could make the calc version robust anyway.  Add it to the list of jobs to do:-)

Comment: latex2e defines `\setcounter` by simple `\def` hence it's not robust, but just by coincidence the fully expansion of `\setcounter{<cnt>}{<num>}` is `\global \c@<cnt>  <num>\relax` when counter `<cnt>` is defined.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I actually don't think `mathtools` currently uses `calc` (quickly looked for the 4 macros). But `empheq` uses it a lot. So for now, the loading of `calc` could probably be moved to `empheq` (and I can have a look at what it uses, and probably rewrite using `\dimexpr` and friends.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I have some generic questions. 1. I know it is good to have a minimal example, but the template is not putting everything in a single "main" file. So how shall I construct a minimal example when I propose questions on Stack Exchange? 2. How can I locate the error? Overleaf suggests some errors in "./output.toc", but when I clicked it, it did not direct me anywhere. Some others are in main.tex, which can be directed to.

Comment: The problem **is** in the `.toc` that is where that `\setcounter` written to. But the error message is important. If the error is in `.toc` or say `.aux` then it is something written to that file in some incompatible way. As for examples, you should always reduce to a single file, this is an important debugging tool. What I did here was to download your example, and then I messed with the `.cls` file and having the compiler ignore parts of it.